# Hyperlink to SVG java/html

Tags: javascript, html, svg, hyperlink

I have been trying to associate a hyperlink to one of the SVGs on a java map downloaded from amcharts.com. The code is:

```js
// svg path for target icon                 
var targetSVG = "M9,0C4.029,0,0,4.029,0,9s4.029,9,9,9s9-4.029,9-9S13.971,0,9,0z M9,15.93 c-3.83,0-6.93-3.1-6.93-6.93S5.17,2.07,9,2.07s6.93,3.1,6.93,6.93S12.83,15.93,9,15.93 M12.5,9c0,1.933-1.567,3.5-3.5,3.5S5.5,10.933,5.5,9S7.067,5.5,9,5.5 S12.5,7.067,12.5,9z";
targetSVG.onclick = function() {
  self.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../ammap/ammap.css" type="text/css">
<script src="../ammap/ammap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- map file should be included after ammap.js -->
<script src="../ammap/maps/js/worldLow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- scripts for exporting chart as an image -->
<!-- Note, the exporting will work only if you view the file from web server -->
<!-- Exporting to image works on all modern browsers except IE9 (IE10 works fine) -->
<!--[if (!IE) | (gte IE 10)]> -->
<script src="../ammap/exporting/amexport.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../ammap/exporting/rgbcolor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../ammap/exporting/canvg.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../ammap/exporting/filesaver.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- <![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript">
```

I am trying to find a solution for the last function I created for 'targetSVG.onclick' which seems not working. I am new to javascript and such applications.
Please help.

Mushi

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. Can you please help me to solve my problem. I will be grateful.

Comment: @Mushi, have you make usage of the code I shared with you ?  In case please mark my answer as accepted

Answer (score 0):

Since the SVG image is displayed in Ammap you can make usage of the available properties and insert the url in a single Point definition.

An example:

```
var city = {
id: "city",
color: "#000000",
svgPath: targetSVG,
url: "http://www.google.com",
urlTarget: "_blank",
latitude: 41.872389,
longitude: 12.48018,
scale: 1.5,
zoomLevel: 7.74,
zoomLongitude: 12.48018,
zoomLatitude: 41.872389,
}
```

Have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/aberna/L0h3eg74/1/ for a demo

You may find more documentation here (http://docs.amcharts.com/javascriptmaps/MapObject)